# How to start application after installation with PackageMaker

Tags: macos, packagemaker

I am wondering how to start an application after installation with PackageMaker. I am receiving tons of emails from my users asking me why the app does not start automatically.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards,

Answer (score 7):

Use the -b option and give the applications bundle identifcation

" -b bundle_indentifier
Specifies the bundle identifier for the application to use when opening the file "

```
  open -b "app.bundle.id"
```

Comment: Just to show you I'm not a sore loser for having you answer this correctly _and_ -1'ing my answer.. I'll +1 you anyway. Because thats how I roll.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel  Do you mean you down voted your own answer?

Comment: I'm just goofin on you. Your answer is better.

Comment: Is there any way to launch the app after user clicked the 'close' button when the app had been successfully installed?

Comment: I had the same question but I do not understand where do I need to write the "open -b <bundleID>". And I also had the same question as @denzel . Thanks.

Comment: can you tell me, where to put this code? @markhunte

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by adding a post install.sh script that has

```
#!/bin/bash

open /Applications/NewlyInstalled.app
```

Comment: but what if the user install it on a different directory? is there a way to get the correct installation directory from somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

What about choosing as postinstall action "Open File" and select as component your app?

Comment: The issue is that the installer requires admin rights to install and the appli will be started with the admin account

Answer (score 2):

Due respect to all above answer, but This is also working after installation with packages which i mention below.

```
open -a 'App Name'
```